# Pass reference to boost array to Class

Tags: c++, arrays

Embarrassingly basic question here... I have a Boost multidimensional array that I'm passing to a Class. I'd like the Class to be able to access the array via the pointer in its member functions. How do I do this?

```
class MyClass {
  public:
   MyClass( boost::multi_array & ); /
  private:
   boost::multi_array& arrPtr;
   void doSomethingInvolvingArray();
}

MyClass::MyClass( boost::multi_array & arr ) {
  arrPtr = arr; // get "uninitialized reference member MyClass::arrPtr" here
}

void MyClass::doSomethingInvolvingArray( ) {
   int i = arrPtr[0][0][1]; // I want to do something like this
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an initializer list in the constructor:

```
MyClass::MyClass( boost::multi_array & arr ) : arrPtr(arr) {}
```

Just note you are using a *reference* in your code, not a *pointer* as you describe in your question.

Comment: Ah, right, it's a reference. It does work in an initializer list in the constructor... need to read up on those. Thanks.